# How to create Evenly-spaced and the unevenly-spaced grids

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a function to test_Lagrange_interpolation().

I need to plot Lagrangian interpolant of (1) built on the grid (2) with N= 8 nodes and evaluated at x.
And 
another plot Lagrangian interpolant of (1) built on the grid (3) withN= 8 nodes and evaluated at x.

So, in other words, to make evenly space grid we can use linspace(-1,1,9)
for unevely space grid what can we use?

Thankx

Comment: Could you please edit your post and tell us what type of unevenly space grid do you want?

Comment: I wan't to know how to create evenly space grid and unevenly space grid in matlab while plotting

Comment: In plotting, you just use `plot(X,Y)`; the grid depends on your `X`, it will become an uneven one when your `X` is uneven. Or if you mean you want an uneven `xticklabel`, just edit it in figures and delete what you needn't.

Comment: Here is the question:  The function should plot (1) (in blue) and the Lagrangian interpolants (in red) obtained by using both the evenly-spaced and the unevenly-spaced grids for the casesN= 8 andN= 20 (4different figures).

Comment: so what does evenly-spaced and the unevenly-spaced grids mean?

Comment: So, you mean the unevenly Lagrangian interpolants? it is another world...Let me try to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have a [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) with type

[image]

- *even grid interpolation* means we generate an even `x` to do interpolation.
- *uneven grid interpolation* means the `x` is an uneven vector.

So, what is the benefit of an uneven interpolation? It is due to some shortage of even interpolation:[Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon), *which is a problem of oscillation at the edges of an interval that occurs when using polynomial interpolation with polynomials of a high degree over a set of equispaced interpolation points.*

In other words, just look at the figure below. The left one is a LaGrange polynomial with even grid and the right one's grid is uneven([Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)), and we could reckon that in this case, the performance of the right one (uneven grid) is better.

[image]

Codes:

```
clc; clear;
syms X
subplot(1,2,1)
ezplot('1/(1+25*x^2)',[-3 3])
Y=0;
xx=-3:0.5:3;
yy=1./(1+25*xx.^2);
for ii=1:length(xx)
  tmp=1;
  for jj=1:length(xx)
    if (jj == ii)
        continue;
    end
    tmp=tmp*(X-xx(jj))/(xx(ii)-xx(jj));
  end
  Y=Y+tmp*yy(ii);
end
hold on
ezplot(Y,[-3 3])
axis([-3 3 0 1.2])
title('even grid')

subplot(1,2,2)
ezplot('1/(1+25*x^2)',[-3 3])
Y2=0;
xx=-cos((0:12)/12*pi)*3;
yy=1./(1+25*xx.^2);
for ii=1:length(xx)
  tmp=1;
  for jj=1:length(xx)
    if (jj == ii)
        continue;
    end
    tmp=tmp*(X-xx(jj))/(xx(ii)-xx(jj));
  end
  Y2=Y2+tmp*yy(ii);
end
hold on
ezplot(Y2,[-3 3])
axis([-3 3 0 1.2])
title('uneven grid')
```

*hope it helps!*